# Is it possible to capture traffic to the remote web server

Tags: networking, remote, security, sniffing, password-protected

I noticed that my user name and password is sent bare text to the remote server inside HTTP POST request. This is a sniffed packed from Wireshark

```
POST /***URL*** HTTP/1.1
Host: ***DNS NAME***
Content-Length: 463
site2pstoretoken=***TOKEN***&ssousername=***MY USER NAME***&password=***MY PASSWORD***
```

This web site doesn't use TSL and is exposed to outer internet network.

**Q1:** Is it possible to sniff incoming traffic to that remote server (and get all the passwords)?

**Q2:** I think that's a security hole, am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A1: A man-in-the-middle attack would definitely be a good way to get this information (say if someone had access to a router / switch in the network).

A2: Yes, very much so. I'd get running on HTTPS as soon as possible.

Comment: +1 to man-in-the-middle attacks. this is so true in proxied environments... the admins can see all un-encrypted content that goes through it.

Comment: Or public wifi hotspots that aren't encrypted or use WEP (i.e. with FireSheep).